# elm decode non-uniform array

Tags: arrays, json, decode, elm

I need to decode a JSON array where the head item is of type `User` and all the tail items are `Nickname`'s. The array length is not known beforehand and I cannot change the JSON representation.

JSON sample:

```
{ "userdata" : [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "MyName",
        "email" : "MyName@dot.com"
    },
    {
        "name" : "n1"
    },
    {
        "name" : "n2"
    }
]
}
```

My type definitions:

```
module Decoders exposing (..)
type alias User =
    { id : Int
    , name : String
    , email : String
    }

type alias Nickname =
    { name : String
    }

type alias Model =
    { user : User
    , nicknames : List Nickname
    }
```

There are many other distinct fields in `User` and `Nickname` but I have shortened it here to keep the example simple.

Decoders:

```
decodeUser : Json.Decode.Decoder User
decodeUser =
    Json.Decode.Pipeline.decode User
        |> Json.Decode.Pipeline.required "id" (Json.Decode.int)
        |> Json.Decode.Pipeline.required "name" (Json.Decode.string)
        |> Json.Decode.Pipeline.required "email" (Json.Decode.string)


decodeNickname : Json.Decode.Decoder Nickname
decodeNickname =
    Json.Decode.Pipeline.decode Nickname
        |> Json.Decode.Pipeline.required "name" (Json.Decode.string)


decodeModel : Json.Decode.Decoder Model
decodeModel =
    Json.Decode.Pipeline.decode Model
        |> Json.Decode.Pipeline.required "userdata" (Json.Decode.index 0 decodeUser)
        |> Json.Decode.Pipeline.hardcoded [ Nickname "Nick", Nickname "Names" ]
```

Test:

```
decodesModel : Test
decodesModel =
    test "Decodes a user and list of nicknames" <|
        \() ->
            let
                input =
                    """
                      { "userdata" : [
                        {
                          "id" : 1,
                          "name" : "MyName",
                          "email" : "MyName@dot.com"
                        },
                        {
                          "name" : "n1"
                        },
                        {
                          "name" : "n2"
                        }
                      ]
                      }
                    """

                decodedOutput =
                    Json.Decode.decodeString
                        Decoders.decodeModel
                        input

                nicknames =
                    [ Decoders.Nickname "n1", Decoders.Nickname "n2" ]

                user =
                    Decoders.User 1 "MyName" "MyName@dot.com"

                expectation =
                    Decoders.Model user nicknames
            in
                Expect.equal decodedOutput
                    (Ok expectation)
```

Since I have just hardcoded the `Nickname` deserialisation the test fails:

```
✗ Decodes a user and list of nicknames

Ok { user = { id = 1, name = "MyName", email = "MyName@dot.com" }, nicknames = [{ name = "n1" },{ name = "n2" }] }
╷
│ Expect.equal
╵
Ok { user = { id = 1, name = "MyName", email = "MyName@dot.com" }, nicknames = [{ name = "Nick" },{ name = "Names" }] }
```

What is the best way of dropping the head item and deserialising the rest of the array into a List of `Nickname`'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this by first making a higher order decoder which takes two decoders as input: the first decoder to decode the head of a list and the second to decode the tail. The signature could be like this:

```elm
headAndTailDecoder : Decoder a -> Decoder b -> Decoder ( a, List b )
```

What follows is my initial attempt at implementing this function. It's a bit verbose because it first decodes a list into a list of `Json.Decode.Value` items, then runs the decoders on the resulting list:

```elm
import Json.Decode as JD exposing (Decoder)
import Result.Extra exposing (combine)

headAndTailDecoder : Decoder a -> Decoder b -> Decoder ( a, List b )
headAndTailDecoder head tail =
    JD.list JD.value
        |> JD.andThen
            (\values ->
                case values of
                    [] ->
                        JD.fail "Empty list"

                    h :: t ->
                        case ( JD.decodeValue head h, List.map (JD.decodeValue tail) t |> combine ) of
                            ( Ok headDecoded, Ok tailDecoded ) ->
                                JD.succeed (headDecoded, tailDecoded)

                            _ ->
                                JD.fail "Invalid"
            )
```

This can probably be optimized, but it gets the job done. Running against your input yields:

```elm
JD.field "userdata" (headAndTailDecoder decodeUser decodeNickname)
    |> JD.map (\(h, t) -> Model h t)

-- yields: Ok { user = { id = 1, name = "MyName", email = "MyName@dot.com" }, nicknames = [{ name = "n1" },{ name = "n2" }] }
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! Nice strategy to decode into `Json.Decode.Value` items for pattern matching.